# Error "A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame" when replacing values in a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to replace the state value from `undefined` to `failed` if the value in `usd_pledged_real` < `usd_goal_real` by running this command:

```
data.loc[(data['state'] == 'undefined') & (data['usd_pledged_real'] < data['usd_goal_real'])]['state'].replace('undefined', 'failed', inplace=True)
```

However, I'm running into this error:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py:6786: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  self._update_inplace(new_data)
```

My dataset:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think `replace` here is not necessary, because set values by condition with testing `undefined`:

```
m = (data['state'] == 'undefined') & (data['usd_pledged_real'] < data['usd_goal_real'])
data.loc[m,'state'] = 'failed'
```

If want use `replace` then is necessary output assign back.

You cannnot use `inplace=True`, because subset returns a `Series` which may have its data as a view. Modifying it in place doesn't ALWAYS propogate it back to the parent object. That's why `SettingWithCopyWarning` is possible there (or raise if you set the option). You should never do this, nor is their ever a reason to do so.

```
m = (data['state'] == 'undefined') & (data['usd_pledged_real'] < data['usd_goal_real'])
data.loc[m,'state'] = data.loc[m,'state'].replace('undefined', 'failed')
```

---

Generally `inplace` is not recommended - [link](https://www.dataschool.io/future-of-pandas/#inplace):

> The pandas core team discourages the use of the **inplace** parameter, and eventually it will be deprecated (which means "scheduled for removal from the library"). Here's why:
>
> **inplace** won't work within a method chain.
> The use of **inplace** often doesn't prevent copies from being created, contrary to what the name implies.
> Removing the **inplace** option would reduce the complexity of the pandas codebase.